# Blending the rendering of DataTableView and a standard view in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to django and have been experimenting with some of the code

I want to build a form that starts with a parent record, lists the children of that record, and then when I click on a child (or a button in the row of that child) shows the children under that in a datatableview object.  *phew*  It should look a little like this:

[image: Conceptual Structure]

So the dataset is the primary object into the view, and the tables are a datatables filtered by the dataset id, which all works fine... but how do I get the {{ datatable }} to render in context?

The current view code is pretty basic - this is initially all just for display.

```
def datasetview(request, datasetid):
    dataset = get_object_or_404(DataSet, pk=datasetid)

    context = {
        'dataset': dataset,
    }
    return render(request, 'data/dataset_view.html', context)
```

within the html template, I render the table  list with:

```
                        {% for datatable in dataset.datatables.all %}
                            {% if not datatable.deleted %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="p-1 align-middle">{{ datatable.tablename }}</td>
                                    <td class="p-1 align-middle"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="fill_attribute_table({{ datatable.datatableid }})">Edit</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
```

I've been able to render the dataviewtable as a generic page using the demo code provided at  [pypi.org/project/django-datatable-view](https://pypi.org/project/django-datatable-view/) (that's how I produced the hacky screen image above) but have no idea how to blend the results here together or pass the datatableid that I can easily attach to the row of tables (the edit button currently throws up an alert with the relevant id...